# How to loop over the flash elements in a Scala template?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having a hard time trying to translate a bit of template from 1.2.4 to 2.0.

So far, I managed to loop through all the flash elements, but I'd like to get the Key and the Message separately (@msgKey contains a list, and I don't know how to split it :/) => `(success, Your data has been updated)`.

Here's the original code:

```
#{if flash.data.size() > 0}
    #{list items:flash.data, as:'msg'}
        #{if msg.key.substring(0, 4).equals('info')}#{set msg_type:'info' /}#{/if}
        #{if msg.key.substring(0, 4).equals('succ')}#{set msg_type:'success' /}#{/if}
        #{if msg.key.substring(0, 4).equals('warn')}#{set msg_type:'warning' /}#{/if}
        #{if msg.key.substring(0, 4).equals('erro')}#{set msg_type:'error' /}#{/if}
        <div class="alert alert-${msg_type}" data-dismiss="alert">  
            <a title="Close that message" class="close">×</a>
            ${msg.value.raw()}
        </div>
    #{/list}
#{/if}
```

And here's the new one :

```
@if(!flash.isEmpty()) {
    @for(msgKey <- flash) { 
        <div class="alert alert-@msgKey" data-dismiss="alert">      
            <a title="@Messages("misc.message.close")" class="close">×</a>
            @msgKey
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a list, it is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I'm veeery new in scala! :p

Comment: You might want to set a proper title for this question!

Comment: What do you suggest, @Somatik ?

Comment: Just submitted an edit but no idea how this peer review works. "How to loop over the flash elements in a scala template?"

Comment: Like this ? :) I had the opportunity to change it! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10228/discussion-between-somatik-and-cx42net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772743/marius) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196899/53013), you can also write this:

```
@if(!flash.isEmpty()) {
    @for((msgKey, msgValue) <- flash) { 
        <div class="alert alert-@msgKey" data-dismiss="alert">      
            <a title="@Messages("misc.message.close")" class="close">×</a>
            @msgKey
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Could you add me an hint on how to check the 4 first strings of the key if order to set the classe name regarding it please? I would apreciate

Comment: Use `@if(msgKey.startsWith("info")){...}` or pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

The data in the flash is a [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map), iterating over it yields a [tuple of two elements](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2), the key and the value. You can access the key with `@msgKey._1` and the value with `@msgKey._2`.

Comment: It would be prettier to pattern match on the tuple, though, as in Daniel C. Sobral's answer.